# How to mock CacheFactory (not $cacheFactory)?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, caching

I'm using CacheFactory provided by angular-cache.js [git link](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) which I need to mock in order to test my factory.
This is the code I'm using in the factory for caching.

```
var cache = CacheFactory.createCache('documentTypeCache', {
              deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
              recycleFreq: 55 * 60 * 1000,
              maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
              storageMode: 'sessionStorage'
            });
```

And this is how I'm mocking it in my tests.

```
mockCacheFactory = function(){
                    this.createCache = jasmine.createSpy('createCache');
                    this.$get = function(){};
                };
                $provide.provider('CacheFactory', mockCacheFactory);
```

However, the tests fail with: `Undefined is not an object` which points to `CacheFactory.createCache`.

I tried googling around but seems like there is not much information available related to angular-cache.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some headBanging, I found a way to make it work. I was mocking createCache in the wrong place. It has to be returned by $get. Below is the code snippet.

```
$provide.provider('CacheFactory', function() {
                    this.$get = function () {
                        return {
                            createCache: jasmine.createSpy('createCache')
                        };
                    }
                });
```

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
mockCacheFactory = {
    createCache: jasmine.createSpy('createCache'),
    $get: angular.noop
};

$provide.provider('CacheFactory', mockCacheFactory);
```

If you're wondering, `angular.noop` can be used as a quick way to return a function with no functionality.